# Which zero bisection method locates?

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

This regarding an exercise from the Numerical Analysis book by Conte and de Boor. The question is the following.

If $a$ and $b$ are such that $f(a)f(b)<0$ and if $f$ has more than one zero in $(a,b)$, which zero the bisection method will locate?

I am not getting any clue in solving this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When there are more than one zeros in a given interval, the "bisection" method will find the one closest to the midpoint of the interval.

Comment: @user247327, I don't think that's true, but I haven't a counterexample right now.

Answer (score 2):

This nice paper addresses precisely this question:

> George Corliss, ["Which root does the bisection algorithm find?"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1019044), *SIAM Review*, 19 (2): 325–327 (1977), [doi:10.1137/1019044](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1019044)

It says that there is zero probability of finding even-numbered roots and equal probability of finding odd-numbered roots.

Comment: "Even numbered roots" ... The paper cited merely says this is well known.  Then the paper goes on to discuss the odd numbered roots.  It seems the roots are simple, and numbered from left to right.  So if there are $3$ roots, $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ we almost never end at the middle one.  I guess the "almost" here is obtained by letting the roots be independent and uniformly distributed in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @GEdgar, exactly, yes. That's my understanding.

Comment: I am wondering how this was given as an exercise in that $elementary$ numerical analysis book.